# using redux along side react-navigation

Tags: redux, react-navigation

Is there a way to let `react-navigation` manage all the navigation aspects while letting `redux` manage the rest without them getting all tangled up.

`react-navigation` is not longer supporting `redux` which makes me pretty sad.

> Warning: in the next major version of React Navigation, to be released in Fall 2018, we will no longer provide any information about how to integrate with Redux and it may cease to work.

I don't really care specifically to have the navigation state managed by the redux store but I do want my display state to be managed there. `react-navigation` requires you passing state around which is fine for small applications but doesn't scale well.

I've got redux working with `react-navigation` by running `connect` on each page that I care about. Everything works fine until you fire and action which nukes the local `react-navigation` state.

Have any of you got `react-navigation` working with `redux` in the way I described above?

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'm doing it.  I found the easiest way was to use "connect" on all of my screens when I create the routes.  I hope this helps:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Route1: {
      screen: setupReduxContainer(Screen1)
    },
      Route2: {
        screen: setupReduxContainer(Screen2)
      }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Route1"
  }
);

export const NavigationContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export function setupReduxContainer(component) {

const Container = component;

  return connect(
    state => ({ ...state })
  )(props => <Container {...props} />);
}


export default () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer />
  </Provider>
);
```