# Why is it bad to store react-navigation state in Redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation, react-state-management

The documentation for react-navigation has a specific section [Can I store the navigation state in Redux too?](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration/#can-i-store-the-navigation-state-in-redux-too).

It says:

> This is not possible. We don't support it because it's too easy to shoot yourself in the foot and slow down / break your app.

I trust that this has been well-researched by the react-navigation team and the community. The presence of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470594/using-redux-along-side-react-navigation) on SO suggests that this *was* supported at some point, but must have been deemed universally bad for some reason.

**What I'd like to know is:** why exactly is "storing navigation state in Redux" a bad practice?

**The answer can be in the form of:**

- specific scenarios in which storing nav state in Redux introduced extra bugs / complexity
- theoretical explanation why nav state is incompatible with Redux store (e.g. "it's hard to make it immutable" )
- links/excerpts from GitHub issues which showcase how exactly the decision was made to advise against storing nav state in Redux
- ...anything else which would make the reader say "oh snap, how could I not think about this" :)

I couldn't find a good explanation with a quick search, and I figured this question would be a good reference for people as curious as myself. I must confess that I often find myself tempted to implement some workaround for this, just to store everything in a single place (e.g. to be able to "replay" for debugging purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, at the last "React Contributor Days", I (for context, a Redux maintainer) brought up that topic and Michael Jackson (a React-Router maintainer) started piggy-backing on it, I remember the whole discussion to be quite interesting.
Of course, all of this is quite the "opinion" topic, and might not give you all the answers, but it might give you some insights on why we don't want to entangle different state sources too much.

I looked it up, here you have a video with a timestamp to where we started the discussion: https://youtu.be/4uLV8ieQVZk?t=3767